# Trivial and non trivial.

Tags: matrices, determinant

How do we know what to do when asked to find the solutions of given equations saying find the solution when it has non trivial solution??

Comment: Can you give an example? This is not at all clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often, solutions that involve a zero are called "trivial". Nonzero solutions or examples are considered to be "nontrivial". For example, the equation $3x+6y=0$ has the trivial solution $(x,y)=(0,0)$, and it has the nontrivial solution $(x,y)= 
 (-2,1)$. 
So, back to your question, when the question tells you to find a nontrivial solution, you need to find a solution of the given equations that does not have a $0$ in it.

Comment: And if it also contains a zero in it..

Comment: I hope I'm understanding your question correctly. If not, please tell me and I'll try to help you again.

Comment: Adding to the answer (which saved me a ton of typing), usually you need to write a variable with respect to the other. For this example, $y=-\frac{1}{2}x$, so any pair which satisfies this condition will solve your equation.

Comment: Ux+vy+wz=0




Uy+vz+wx=0
   Uz+vx+wy=0   are the three Equation and question is it has non trivial solutions then find the values of x y z.. What will be the condition to do so..

Comment: user443149, can you edit your question so that it says that? Your comment is now going off the screen, so I can't fully see it. I can answer it if it is put in the actual question.

Comment: Answer a simple question if there are three equations given and all three are equated to zero and the have non trivial solutions.. What would you do to find the solutions using determinants..